# Solidity array returning as string in node js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, quorum

I am learning solidity basics , in solidity i can able to write a data in string array
but i am not able to retrieve string array in my node js call.i have tried with JsonRpcProvider and also web3 both are returning same result.

```
struct StrData{
      
      string dhash;
       uint sizeOfMapping;
        mapping(uint => string) strDataMap;
  }
  StrData data;
 
function set(string memory x) public {
     data.strDataMap[data.sizeOfMapping++] = x;
   
   
  }

  function get() public view returns (string[] memory) {
      
      string[] memory memoryArray = new string[](data.sizeOfMapping);
        for(uint i = 0; i < data.sizeOfMapping; i++) {
             memoryArray[i] = data.strDataMap[i];
        }
        return memoryArray;
   
  }
```

from node js , i am calling this to get array but i am always getting string array as string like ['x','y']

Any conversion i have to do in node js to get object as array instead of string?

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  


    result = await Contract.methods.get().call(function (err, result) {
        console.log('get result',result)
       
        res.send(result);
        
    });
  
    
    
})
```